# Get nullable property or throw exception

Tags: kotlin

I recently switch from java to kotlin. I have following method in my code and I would like to ask if there is better way how to write it in kotlin?

This is my parsing method which parse `id` from object `obj` which has nullable property `nullableNestedObject` and this object had `id` property.

```
fun parseId(obj: WrappingObject): Long {
    val myId = obj.nullableNestedObject?.myId

    if (myId === null) {
        logger.error("Id not found because of ...")
        throw InternalException("Id not found")
    }
    return myId
}
```

Comment: don't throw an exception but return a nullable type instead `Long?`

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it a bit by putting the relevant code into a [`run()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) call:

```
fun parseId(obj: WrappingObject): Long
    = obj.nullableNestedObject?.myId
        ?: run {
            logger.error("ID not found because of...")
            throw InternalException("ID not found")
        }
```

Run is a [scoping function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html) that provides a simple way to group lines of code into a block.

(If the block didn't throw an exception, it would have to return a Long value too, of course.)

You'll notice I've made it into a [single-expression function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#single-expression-functions) — it's shorter, and easier to see what it returns. (That's only appropriate for fairly short functions, though.)

<sup>(I've also capitalised ‘ID’, which is a bugbear of mine: it's an abbreviation, and pronounced as two letters, so both should be capitalised. Otherwise, it looks just like the [term from psychoanalysis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/id#Noun)…)</sup>

Another change you might consider is to make it an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions) on `WrappingObject`:

```
fun WrappingObject.parseId(): Long
    = nullableNestedObject?.myId
        ?: run {
            logger.error("ID not found because of...")
            throw InternalException("ID not found")
        }
```

That way, it can be called as `myWrappingObject.parseId()`, just as if it were a method of WrappingObject. That can keep the namespace a little clearer, and lets your IDE suggest it.

---

As per Tulip's answer, this would be even simpler if you didn't need to call the logger as well:

```
fun parseId(obj: WrappingObject): Long
    = obj.nullableNestedObject?.myId
        ?: throw InternalException("ID not found")
```

When I write custom exceptions, I tend to write a log entry in the constructor, which enables that sort of simplicity as well as avoiding duplication of the log calls.

Answer (score 1):

Just another variation on the same theme, just because I find scoping functions and brackets sometimes make the code less simple

```
fun WrappingObject.parseId() = nullableNestedObject?.myId ?: logAndThrow()

private fun logAndThrow() : Nothing {
    logger.error("ID not found because of...")
    throw InternalException("ID not found")
}
```

Comment: You'll need to declare `logAndThrow()` as returning `Nothing` (indicating it never returns normally) — otherwise, it returns `Unit`, and so `parseId()` returns `Any` (the nearest common superclass of `Unit` and `Long`).

Comment: Good point @gidds. That'll teach me to do a quick-copy-and-paste job.

Answer (score 0):

If your Long value can be nullable, you can use this way, and check null or not null later

```
fun parseId(obj: WrappingObject): Long? {
    return obj.nullableNestedObject?.myId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for concise (i.e. minimal) code, I suggest using the elvis operator (`?:`) and the `run` scope function:

```
fun parseId(obj: WrappingObject): Long = obj.nullableNestedObject?.myId ?: run {
        logger.error("Id not found because of ...")
        throw InternalException("Id not found")
    }
```